# How do I use stack content in an LLDB breakpoint condition?

Tags: xcode, lldb

**The problem:**

I've got a situation where we have a media playback during launch, and objc_exception_throw() hits about 5 times during that period, but is always caught, and it's *way* south of the media player object.

I'm tired of either (a) having to manually continue n times, or (b) having to leave breakpoints disabled until after the playback is complete.

**What I've tried:**

- making the breakpoint ignore the first five hits (problem: it's not always exactly five times)
- creating my own symbolic breakpoint using my target as the module (problem: nothing changed)

**What I'd like to do:**

One solution that comes to mind is to evaluate the stack when the breakpoint hits, and continue if a particular method or function is listed therein. But I have no idea how to do this.

Other ideas welcome as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You do it using Python.

The following defines an ignore list and a function you can attach as a command to a breakpoint.

The function grabs the names of functions in the backtrace and set-intersects those names with the ignore list. If any names match, it continues running the process. This effectively skips dropping into the debugger for unwanted stacks.

```
(lldb) b objc_exception_throw
Breakpoint 1: where = libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, address = 0x00000000000113c5
(lldb) script
Python Interactive Interpreter. To exit, type 'quit()', 'exit()' or Ctrl-D.
>>> ignored_functions = ['recurse_then_throw_and_catch']
def continue_ignored(frame, bp_loc, dict):
    global ignored_functions
    names = set([frame.GetFunctionName() for frame in frame.GetThread()])
    all_ignored = set(ignored_functions)
    ignored_here = all_ignored.intersection(names)
    if len(ignored_here) > 0:
        frame.GetThread().GetProcess().Continue()

quit()

(lldb) br comm add -F continue_ignored 1
(lldb) r
```

I tried it against the following file, and it successfully skips the first throw inside `recurse_then_throw_and_catch` and drops into the debugger during the throw inside `throw_for_real`.

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void
f(int n)
{
    if (n <= 0) @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"plugh" reason:@"foo" userInfo:nil];

    f(n - 1);
}

void
recurse_then_throw_and_catch(void)
{
    @try {
        f(5);
    } @catch (NSException *e) {
        NSLog(@"Don't care: %@", e);
    }
}

void
throw_for_real(void)
{
    f(2);
}

int
main(void)
{
    recurse_then_throw_and_catch();
    throw_for_real();
}
```

I imagine you could add this function to your `.lldbinit` and then connect it to breakpoints as needed from the console. (I don't think you can set a script command from within Xcode.)

Comment: Damn, dude. Best answer I could've hoped for.

Comment: Nice answer.  The only caveat is that this will `continue` if any of `ignored_functions` appears anywhere on the stack, instead of merely checking the frame "above" `objc_exception_throw`.

Comment: @JasonMolenda Entirely correct. "Anywhere on the stack" was what I figured was wanted based on "evaluate the stack when the breakpoint hits, and continue if a particular method or function is listed therein". It would be simple to adapt to do `if frame.GetThread().GetFrameAtIndex(1).GetFunctionName() in ignored_functions:` instead. The key insight is to use a Python function as the breakpoint command.

Comment: Note also that starting with Xcode 5's lldb, lldb checks the return value from Python breakpoint commands, and if they return a boolean value of False, lldb will continue from the breakpoint.  Maybe that's a little easier than having to call "continue" by hand.  It also means that if you hit two breakpoints simultaneously (which does happen in threaded code) lldb will only continue if both breakpoint hits want to continue.

Answer (score 4):

```
break command add -s python -o "return any('xyz' in f.name for f in frame.thread)"
```

If a python breakpoint command returns `False`, lldb will keep going. So this is saying: if `any` frame in the stack has the string `'xyz'` in its name, then return `True` (to stop). Otherwise if no frame has that name, this `any` expression will return `False` (to keep going).