# Is there a way to enable/disable a breakpoint other than by its ID?

Tags: c++, xcode, lldb

Using LLDB (version 179.5, with XCode 4.6.3), is there a command that I can use to disable a breakpoint by specifying a symbol name, rather than a numeric ID?

Context: I'm using Boost.Spirit (classic) to parse a file, and as part of the parsing, many exceptions may be thrown and then caught. It's not useful to break when the exceptions are thrown, but I'd like to break when exceptions are thrown outside of Spirit.

I can get the behaviour I want for a single run using conditional breakpoints - first, I use `break list` to find the numeric ID of the `__cxa_throw` breakpoint. Suppose it turns out to be `2`. Then I can set a breakpoint before invoking Spirit, set it to continue after evaluating, and add an LLDB action `break disable 2`. Then I set another similar breakpoint after Spirit returns, with `break enable 2`.

The problem is, I can't rely on the numeric IDs to remain the same across several invocations of the program. I'd like to be able to set up something that doesn't require me to fix it every time I run the program.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922859/how-do-i-use-stack-content-in-an-lldb-breakpoint-condition) which looks like it might be able to achieve a similar result, though I would prefer the enable/disable approach since it is more flexible (eg, allowing you to ignore the breakpoints in some areas of your code but not others). I'm also not entirely clear whether I need to do anything extra to get lldb to use `.lldb_init` when called by Xcode, though.

Answer (score 0):

In the lldb from Xcode 7 (or current TOT lldb.llvm.org lldb) you can name breakpoints as you make them in the command line.  Then you can enable & disable breakpoints by name.  If you are setting up breakpoints in your .lldbinit, you can make them with names & refer to the names.  But this won't help you very much if you are making the breakpoints in Xcode, since that doesn't have facility for setting a name yet.

Xcode will always read your ~/.lldbinit file - but it has to be in your home directory and the file name has no underscore.  Actually it is a little more complex than that, if you have a file called ~/.lldbinit-Xcode, then that one will get used by Xcode instead of the .lldbinit.  That way if you want some commands run in command line lldb and some in Xcode, you can arrange that.

Comment: That's great to know; unfortunately, I'm stuck on XCode 4.6. (Plus, I'm making the breakpoints with XCode, though I could probably make an exception for the __cxa_throw one.)

Comment: @celticminstrel s/4.6/6.4/g

Comment: Nope. 4.6. XCode 5 and later require Mountain Lion.