# How do I get lldb to stop at a line within a function if that function is called from a certain other function?

Tags: c, debugging, lldb

I have a C code written by someone else, and I'm trying to debug it using lldb. There is a function, `function1()` that calls another, `function2()`, which can also be called by a third function, `function3()`. Is there a way to have lldb stop at a breakpoint in `function2()` only if the function that calls it is `function1()`?

Comment: Not sure, hope this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922859/how-do-i-use-stack-content-in-an-lldb-breakpoint-condition

Comment: @halfelf Thanks. I did see a similar solution, but I was wondering if there was something simpler that was already built in lldb. In my case, `function1()` is called first, so I guess I'll just print something when it completes, so that if it stops after that I'll know it was `function2()` that failed.

Comment: If you have an idea for a way this could be expressed (maybe some kind of breakpoint options, caller name + how far up on the stack to look?) then please file an enhancement request with the llvm.org bugzilla.  For the most part, lldb offloads the fancier breakpoint actions to the Python API's but if there's a popular feature that can be easily expressed in the lldb breakpoint commands, it would make sense to add it.  Double points if you want to try to add the feature yourself ;-)

Comment: Hey @sodiumnitrate, I found your problem to be an interesting one, so I made this into a LLDB script which can be found here: https://github.com/DerekSelander/LLDB/blob/master/lldb_commands/breakifonfunc.py

`biof` will create a regex breakpoint and will only stop if regex2 can be found in the stack trace
ex. If I wanted to break on `setTintColor:` in UIKit only if it's being called from any code in my app, TestApp, I could do the following: 

`(lldb) biof setTintColor: UIKit ||| . TestApp`

@JimIngham, you're a god among mortals. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Also added the `-d` option for direct call on `biof`, so now if you did `biof -d setTintColor: UIKit ||| . TestApp`, it would only stop if a function in TestApp directly called `setTintColor:`.  This varies from the original logic without the `--direct_call` option where it only searches for a method in TestApp to exist in the backtrace